# adb not detecting HTC one X after flashing android 4.3

Tags: android, adb, htc-android

I have installed the drivers. In device manager "Android USB devices" also showed "My HTC" is detected.

However, adb is not able to detect the phone. This only happen after i flash 4.3 cyanogenmod rom.

How to get adb to detect the phone?

Comment: which adb version are you using ?, you can check it by `adb version`

Comment: @Rilwan adb version 1.0.31. does it matter?

Comment: 1.0.31 is the latest, could you please check if `USB debugging` is enabled or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with under **Settings -> Storage -> USB** Computer Connection and  manually select the connection mode.. and connect to computer. Let it install, switch back to USB mode and plug in again.

Comment: This worked for me but to clarify the 'Media Device (MTP)' option should be selected. Mine was originally 'mass storage'